# PHP convert any value into a string?

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to convert any value especially boolean and arrays into strings? I want to do this for a cleaner error message in a function. Right now all I can get in this example below it this for an error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: $argument cannot be in /file.php:## Stack trace: #0 /file.php:(##): myFunction(false) #1 {main} thrown in /file.php on line 47
```

I want it to say "$argument cannot be false" not "$argument cannot be "

```
<?php

myFunction(false);
myFunction(array('a', 'b'));

//Version 0.5
function myFunction($argument) {
    if (!is_string($argument)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$argument cannot be ' . strval($argument));
    }

    //...
}

?>
```

Comment: Would declaring a type be appropriate for your situation? `function (string $argument)`

Comment: You used `strval($string)` but nowhere declared `$string`?

Comment: `(string)true === '1'` and `(string)false === ''`. Welcome to PHP.

Comment: However, you can `json_encode($argument)` or `gettype($argument)` for a textual depiction or description of the value or type.

Comment: Typo: `$argeument` vs `$arguement`?  Also swap `'...'`pair to a `"...."` pair?

Comment: @bhutto54 something to keep in mind on SO, is even though you are just making up a quick rough example of what you mean, everyone is still going to pick it apart for syntax errors and other non-question-related stuff.

Comment: What is the point of this? You should probably just make use of [type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (aka type hinting). Declare your parameter as `string` and you'll get an accurate enough `TypeError` exception automatically thrown. It won't contain the value of your argument, but I don't see exactly how that would help, as long as you know the parameter's position.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to convert most value types to string is using `json_encode`.

An array for example would become `["a","b"]`.

Just `json_encode($argument)`

Comment: Note, this works for serializable content to some degree (a large array might be counter-productive to include). I would still recommend a type declaration for the function argument, enabling static checking for many scenarios, and omit defensive programming, a different discussion than the question asks..

Comment: Thank you, this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `gettype` and/or `var_export`:

```
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$argeument cannot be ' . gettype($argeument) . ' ' . var_export($argeument, true));
```

Or buffer output of `var_dump` and you can see it all:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($argeument);
$text = ob_get_clean();
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$argeument cannot be ' . $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (in lieu of `function (string $value)`, which I recommend)?

```
class InvalidArgumentType extends InvalidArgumentException
{
    public function __construct(int $position, string $requiredType, $value)
    {
        $encoded = json_encode($value);
        
        if (strlen($encoded) > 10) {
            $encoded = sprintf('%s ... %s', substr($encoded, 0, 10), substr($encoded, -1));
        }
        
        $inferredType = is_object($value) ? get_class($value) : gettype($value);
        
        parent::__construct(sprintf(
            'Argument %d value %s should be %s but is %s.',
            $position,
            $encoded,
            $requiredType,
            $inferredType
        ));
    }
}

class Foo {}

echo (new InvalidArgumentType(1, 'string', new Foo()))->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
echo (new InvalidArgumentType(2, 'string', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
echo (new InvalidArgumentType(3, 'string', 123))->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
echo (new InvalidArgumentType(2, 'string', null))->getMessage();
```

Gives:

```
Argument 1 value {} should be string but is Foo.
Argument 2 value [1,2,3,4,5 ... ] should be string but is array.
Argument 3 value 123 should be string but is integer.
Argument 2 value null should be string but is NULL.
```

https://3v4l.org/ko7o1